# Replace special characters the exact same way as Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to reformat `the_title();` the exact same way as Wordpress does with the permalinks.

"Borislav Pekić" becomes "borislav-pekic", "Alberto Méndez" becomes "alberto-mendez" and so on.

```
<?php
    $forfattare = the_title();
?>
```

I've tried to find the way Wordpress does it, but i can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this:

```
 <?php function createAlias($name)
 {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name);
    $alias = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $name);
    $alias = strtolower(trim($alias, '-'));
    $alias = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", "-", $alias);


    while (substr($alias, -1, 1) == "-") {
        $alias = substr($alias, 0, -1);
    }
    while (substr($alias, 0, 1) == "-") {
        $alias = substr($alias, 1, 100);
    }

    return $alias;
}
```

Comment: Here a demo: [Demo on OnlinePHPfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6a71e037a10859ce5c83fe2c211d290a61cd093) So, yes, it does.

Comment: Looks good in your demo but on my WP site it doesn't work. The admin-bar disappears etc.

Comment: I think you misplaced this function somewhere on a wrong place in a file, and it is generating an error now.

Comment: This did the trick: `<?php $string = get_the_title() ;
$forfattare = createAlias( $string ); 
?>` Thanks for your help.